# Sharepoint 2010 UploadCtl Control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I followed the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264294%28v=office.12%29 making a new SP project with the under _layouts. the control renders fine, and i can select files, however when I click upload it shows the little loading icons. with no files uploaded.

```
 <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/_layouts/1033/styles/ows.css">

 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
   function MultipleUploadView() {
       document.all.idUploadCtl.SetTreeViewColor("#FF0000");
       document.all("idMultipleView").style.display = "inline";
   }

   function DocumentUpload() {
       document.all.idUploadCtl.MultipleUpload();
   }
   </SCRIPT>

   <FORM NAME="frmUpload" METHOD="post"
   ACTION="upload.aspx?RootFolder=&amp; Source=http://jono-pc/Shared Documents/Forms   /AllItems.aspx">

  <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server" />
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="Cmd" VALUE="Save">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="NextUsing"
   VALUE="http://jono-pc/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" VALUE="New">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="putopts" VALUE="true">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="destination"
  VALUE="http://jono-pc/Shared Documents">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="Confirmation-URL"
  VALUE="http://jono-pc/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="PostURL"
  VALUE="http://jono-pc/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/_layouts/upload.aspx" />
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="VTI-GROUP" VALUE="0">

  <P CLASS="ms-toolbar">
  <A HREF="javascript:MultipleUploadView()"
  TARGET="_self">Upload Multiple Files</A>
  </P>
  <DIV ID=idMultipleView style='display:none'>
  <P CLASS="ms-toolbar">
  <A HREF="javascript:DocumentUpload()"
  TARGET="_self">Save and Close</A>
  </P>
  <OBJECT id=idUploadCtl name=idUploadCtl
  CLASSID=CLSID:07B06095-5687-4d13-9E32-12B4259C9813
  WIDTH='100%' HEIGHT='350px'>
  </OBJECT>
  </DIV>
  </FORM>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer to this dilemma (hint provided by an old SP bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2489168) The input values must be relative URLS because SharePoint Office 2010 appends the http:// to all the values. so if you have a full URL it will append the http:// twice. Once I changed to relative paths, it uploaded fine.